# SVN working copy too old after upgrade

Tags: svn

I have a SVN working copy on my remote server and recently had to replace some files on it with files from an old server.  I just copied them over and then commit them.  Now, today, I worked on some files on my local copy and commit them.  When I tried to update the working copy on the remote server, it says that my working copy is too old and I need to upgrade.

So, I went to the command prompt and did a `svn upgrade` in the root of the remote working copy.  However, when I try to update, I still get the same error message.  It seems as though the upgrade did nothing.

Comment: What version of SVN was the working copy checked out with?  What version are you currently using?

Comment: `svn --version` gives me 1.8.10.  I'm not sure how to check what version the working copy was checked out with, though.  There is no `.svn/format` or `.svn/entries`.

Comment: Check that the directories you replaced from the old server did not contain any `.svn` hidden directories within them. If they did, remove them and attempt `svn up` again.

Comment: The old server did not run any version control systems and I checked and could not find any `.svn` directories on it.

Answer (score 0):

Already solved a similar issue before by using Tortoise SVN. I just add to do a clean up on my project then an upgrade of my working copy. This could do the trick.